# Admin new order create payment methods not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, admin-order-create

If we create new order from admin, we are not able to see the payment methods http://prntscr.com/fonc01

But while when order from frontend, payment methods are showing fine.

can any help me on this issue.

thanks

Comment: click on get shipping rates, and select a shipping method. See then if you have any payment methods.

Comment: clicked but not showing methods